# Change default country in OpenCart

Tags: opencart2.x

I'm using latest version of OpenCart 2.0.2.0 whenever I go to register page site/index.php?route=account/register it shows United states as default. I know how to change this default country to another default country. Here what I need is, if a user go to register page it will show please select instead of any default country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not option available. but, You can do with modified following code.

**Find code:** catalog\controller\account\register.php

```
if (isset($this->request->post['country_id'])) {
            $data['country_id'] = $this->request->post['country_id'];
        } elseif (isset($this->session->data['shipping_address']['country_id'])) {
            $data['country_id'] = $this->session->data['shipping_address']['country_id'];
        } else {
            $data['country_id'] = $this->config->get('config_country_id');
        }
```

**Remove following code from above code.**

```
else {
            $data['country_id'] = $this->config->get('config_country_id');
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm presently working with custom built OpenCart theme, whenever I visit the register page, by default US is showing. If I want to change the default country (US) to another I need to change it via backend. But I would like to display --Please Select -- option on register page country section. Is there any way to change any default country to please select option?

Answer (score 1):

Goto System -> Settings

You can find a list.

click the edit button

then click on the 'Local' Tab

Change your default country from here.

Answer (score 0):

Another option how to do this is going to the template file, and modifying the loop there to not select the current country.

The area where you have:

```html
<select name="country_id" id="input-country" class="form-control">
  <option value="">
    <?php echo $text_select; ?>
  </option>
  <?php foreach ($countries as $country) { ?>
  <?php if ($country['country_id'] == $country_id) { ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $country['country_id']; ?>" selected="selected">
    <?php echo $country['name']; ?>
  </option>
  <?php } else { ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $country['country_id']; ?>">
    <?php echo $country['name']; ?>
  </option>
  <?php } ?>
  <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Just remove the part where the script is going to make a select element with "selected", like this, this should be the end code:

```html
<select name="country_id" id="input-country" class="form-control">
  <option value="">
    <?php echo $text_select; ?>
  </option>
  <?php foreach ($countries as $country) { ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $country['country_id']; ?>">
    <?php echo $country['name']; ?>
  </option>
  <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: This question already has several answers, including one which has been accepted. Additional information is probably more helpful as a comment.

Comment: fixed it with an alternative solution